# Where to get an older pbacc.dll for PowerBuilder

Tags: dll, windows-10, compatibility, powerbuilder

I try to run a program which was build upon PowerBuilder version **10.2.1.9637** on a **Windows 10** computer. After startup it shows an error message:

> Error loading library. Please check whether PowerBuilder Accessibility library can be located in the path.

Doing some research I found out that there is a pbaccess***.dll needed to get the program run under Windows 10. However, is there a way to get this .dll since I do not own this specific version of PowerBuilder?
Or are there any other workarounds to get the program run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from an earlier build of PB 10.2.1, but you can see if it works.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6J5FirdQZquUFgwVmdkb1QtT28

Answer (score 0):

You would have to get pbacc100.dll from the application developer. Alternately you can disable accessibility in control panel.

Comment: thank you, but what do you mean by "control panel"? The windows control panel?

Comment: Yes. There is a setting that can turn off accessibility. Under Windows 10 I'm not sure if it is technically part of Control Panel or just the new settings interface.